# Last flag was declined message keeps being shown a week later and after reviewing - flagged answer was deleted

Tags: bug, flags, declined-flags

I raised a flag for an answer I found offensive. This flag was declined in review. OK, no problem so far, the system works and this can be expected.

Now, when I raise a new flag, I get the message:

> Your last flag has been declined, please review it before flagging this post!

That all working as expected as well.

However, the message does keep appearing even after reviewing the flag, and it's been over a week now since this flag was declined. **I think this may be because the answer I flagged was removed after I flagged it, but before I could review my declined flag**.

Is this how it is supposed to work, or is this a defect?

---

Update: the message seems to have disappeared now, after a week. Still posting this question to make sure there is no defect here.

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation: I flagged an answer, which in my eyes was an [obvious comment posted as answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43964869/1271826), I flagged it as such, my flag was declined (I disagree, but so be it), and now I can't flag anything else (even though I have 99 available flags and my flagging history is very positive with 3 declines in the previous 165 post flags). For a site that wants our user contributions to the process, it's really weird to shut someone down because of one decline.)

Comment: Also, even if there's some logic behind the "don't let this user flag anything until x", we should at least change the error message. To tell us to "review" it is very useless at best, as misleading at worst (it suggests there's something I should do to return to Stack Overflow's good graces, but apparently there isn't). The error should be change to give us some clue as to what triggered this state of "you cannot flag anymore" and give us some clue as to what must transpire before we can flag again.