# What will satisfy "please review it" and make it go away?

Tags: support

> Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

I clicked review and looked at the post and agree it is now an answer, albeit still looking more like a comment.

When does the above warning go away?

Comment: I think it'll persist until you get one (a couple?) helpful flags after that.

Comment: When your next flag is marked helpful? Just try it and let us know ;)

Comment: Ok, I will :)...

Comment: Be careful, don't get flag banned in the process ...

Comment: Related: [Last flag was declined message keeps being shown a week later and after reviewing - flagged answer was deleted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329858/247702)